# Render multiple videos in seperate canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, twilio, webrtc

I am making a video chat application wherein I want to show images of every user who is connected to the room. Initially I want to show the canvases at the bottom of the application and once a user clicks on a specific canvas the respective canvas would stretch and open in the browser window.
Users Connected:
[image]

In the above image it is visible that multiple users are connected but only 1 user is shown in the canvas when I close the respective div which shows the users connected.

[image]
I want to create a separate canvas for each user who is connected and display his image in the bar at the bottom.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any code you have?

Comment: I am using webrtc and twilio.Here is the code for the publish the video as image to the canvas.
`setInterval(function() {
  let video=document.querySelector('#remote-media video');
  let canvas=document.querySelector('canvas');
  let context=canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = 320;
  canvas.height = 200;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}, 100);`

Comment: @ImeshChandrasiri above is the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your code from your comment seems to suggest that you are only selecting one of the videos (because you are using `querySelector`) and that's why only one is showing up.

As an aside, I would recommend against using `setInterval` for this sort of thing, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) would be better as it runs specifically for animating and showing moving images.

I would try something like this:

```
function drawVideos() {
  const videoContainer = document.querySelector('#remote-media');
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const height = 200;
  const width = 320;
  canvas.height = height;

  function drawFrame() {
    const videos = videoContainer.querySelectorAll('video');
    canvas.width = videos.length * width;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i = 0, len = videos.length; i < len; i++) {
      const video = videos[i];
      context.drawImage(video, i * width, 0, width, height);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
}
```

That is untested and I worry about scope issues, but it might be a start.

The other thing worth checking is that you are only looking within the `#remote-media` element and presumably one of your videos is local media.

Anyway, give that a go and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I want to create a separate canvas for each video I receive. But the above code does not do that I suppose.

I am still learning js so please help me out.

Comment: Ok, sure, then you'll need to create as many canvases as you have videos and then draw on them like above. Give it a go, and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Here's what I tried:  
`function x() {  
  let canv, context, vids;  
  let vid = document.querySelector('#remote-media video');  
  for(let i=0; i<vid.length; i++) {  
    let c = 'c'+i;  
    canv = document.querySelector(c);  
  }  
      context = canv.getContext('2d');  
  canv.width = 300;  
  canv.height = 200;  
  for(let j=0; j< vid.length; j++) {  
    vids = vid[i];  
    context.drawImage(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);  
  }  
}`

Here c would be the id for each canvas that is created and s is the id for each video that is coming.

Comment: OK, and did that work? I don't think you need that inner loop using `j` by the way.

Comment: I took code as a start and worked my way out and was able to display multiple streams in separate canvases.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fantastic news! Hope the rest of the app goes well.